# how to apply background color all pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, colors, background

I try to change background colors all pages in app.
User can select color from a pallete in SettingsPage.

```
Wrap(
            children: List<Widget>.generate(
              mainColor.length,
              (index) => GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedColor = index;
                    box.write('_selectedColor', index);
                    box.write(
                        'color0',
                        mainColor[index]
                            .toString()
                            .split('(')[1]
                            .split(')')[0]);
                  });
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                      child: _selectedColor == index
                          ? const Icon(Icons.done,
                              size: 16, color: Colors.white)
                          : null,
                      backgroundColor: mainColor[index],

                      radius: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I have list of background colors.

```
List<Color> mainColor = [
  const Color(0xffEF5350),
  const Color(0xffF44336),
  const Color(0xffBDBDBD),
  const Color(0xff9E9E9E),
  const Color(0xffEC407A),
  const Color(0xffE91E63),
];
```

I read color in other pages like below

```
backgroundColor: Color(int.parse(box.read('color0'))),
```

My problem is when i navigate back to previous page, color changes not apply. If i start app again, color changes applied.

Comment: could you add the part you read the data from cache and also the part that you use that variable for background color?

Comment: backgroundColor: Color(int.parse(box.read('color0'))),

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is not working is that your previous pages doesn't notify when  ever the background color changes. First define new class like this and call it `CustomBackground`:

```
class CustomBackground with ChangeNotifier {
  Color _backgroundColor = Colors.white;

  Color get backgroundColor => _backgroundColor;

  Future<void> changeBackgroundColor(Color color, GetStorage box) async {
    _backgroundColor = color;
    box.write('color0', color.toString()
                        .split('(')[1]
                        .split(')')[0]);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

then use it like this in your app:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Provider.of<CustomBackground>(context, listen: false).backgroundColor,
  ...
)
```

also don't forget to wrap your main `MaterialApp` with `ChangeNotifierProvider` in order to access your `CustomBackground` in every page of your app:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CustomBackground>(
      create: (_) => CustomBackground(),
      child: Consumer<CustomBackground>(
        builder: (context, backgroundColor, _) {
          return MaterialApp(
             ...
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

and finally change your `onTap` to this:

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    _selectedColor = index;
    box.write('_selectedColor', index);
    Provider.of<CustomBackground>(context, listen: false).changeBackgroundColor(mainColor[index], box);
  });
},
```